# Joining condition failing

Tags: sql-server, join

I have 2 tables. One is #crecs that stores list of CIDs and a #temp1 that stores clone CVIDs. For the ID in the Crecs table, I want to loop through the #temp1 table to find max(CVID) and pull out the date of the Cloned CVID for that CID based on a condition.

I have boiled down the requirement to below tables:

```
    create table #temp1(cid int,cvid int,flag varchar(5), date1 date, clone int)
insert into #temp1
values ('43','1001','A','1/1/2015',null),
        ('43','1002','R','2/1/2015',1001),
        ('43','1003','R','3/1/2015',1002),
        ('43','1004','R','4/1/2015',1003)

create table #crecs(cid int)
insert into #crecs values(43),(44),(45)

select * from #crecs
select * from #temp1
```

My query:

```
select t2.cid,max(t2.cvid),t2.clone,t1.cvid,t1.date1
from #temp1 t2 , #temp1 t1
join #crecs c on c.cid = t1.cid
where t2.clone = t1.cvid
and t1.clone is null and t1.flag = 'A'
group by t2.cid,t2.cvid,t2.clone,t1.cvid,t1.date1

drop table #temp1,#crecs
```

Desired output:
[image]

Below is my rextester link:

http://rextester.com/GSIG28211

Any help?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to travel through each clone, then retrieve the last level with MAX() and display it's record.

```
;WITH RecursiveClones AS
(
    SELECT
        CID = C.cid,
        OriginalCVID = T.cvid,
        ClonedCVID = T.cvid,
        Level = 0
    FROM
        #crecs AS C
        LEFT JOIN #temp1 AS T ON C.cid = T.cid
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'does not have a clone' FROM #temp1 AS X WHERE X.cvid = T.clone)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CID = R.cid,
        OriginalCVID = R.OriginalCVID,
        ClonedCVID = T.cvid,
        Level = R.Level + 1
    FROM
        RecursiveClones AS R
        INNER JOIN #temp1 AS T ON R.ClonedCVID = T.clone
),
LastCloneByCID AS
(
    SELECT
        R.CID,
        MaxLevel = MAX(R.Level)
    FROM
        RecursiveClones AS R
    GROUP BY
        R.CID
)
SELECT
    L.CID,
    R.ClonedCVID,
    R.OriginalCVID,
    T.date1
FROM
    LastCloneByCID AS L
    LEFT JOIN RecursiveClones AS R ON
        L.CID = R.CID AND
        L.MaxLevel = R.Level
    LEFT JOIN #temp1 AS T ON 
        T.cid = L.CID AND
        T.CVID = R.OriginalCVID
```